# In Blender, Can we edit Face Normals?

Tags: faces, normals

I know that we can edit Split Normals. But I can't find a way to edit the Face Normals. Is there any way to edit Face Normals?
[image]

Comment: It is working in 3.5 version as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BY-NGeRzuPQ all credit to the author of the video

Comment: have checked the link. No, this is Split Normals. I am asking about Face Normals

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem You can't. You can edit all face corners of a face to affect the resulting normal of a face, but what Blender displays for a face normal (and what shader reads as "True normal") are vectors perpendicular to the face, and as such, the only way to "change" them is to move the vertices and therefore affect the plane of the face (the angle).

Answer (score 1):

To flip the rotation of a face normal you select the faces you want to flip in the edit mode and press Alt + N -> Flip. Is this what you are looking for? or what do you mean by edit face normals?

[image]

Before flipping

[image]

After flipping

Comment: No, not flipping. I want more freedom to edit Face Normals. Just like you can rotate, point to target,... for Split. I want more freedom to edit Face Normals, not flip only.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you expect to do with it? Face normals are calculated as a perpendicular directional vector to the face. As such the only way to manipulate with them is manipulating the face itself. You can do kind of normal postprocessing within material using normal map, but that's just visual. Other than that I see no way to do this (and I see no reason either).

Comment: I want to rotate instances based on the face normal. Basically to make something like this lego egg: https://www.thebrickman.com/wp-content/uploads/Build_An_Egg.png

Comment: Ah, you are the one that I am recreating the GN for right now=D In this case this is not how to do it! You just want to rotate the whole object in the direction of a normal vector. Not change the direction of separate normals. Wait a sec and I'll upload the answer in the other question